# Simple Text Prediction

Tags: swift, protocols

This is a simple implementation of text prediction using a list of keywords and `UITextChecker`.

This is working correctly, but I think I could have implemented better. My goal is to use a protocol oriented approach.

```
protocol KeywordSuggester {
    func suggestion(word: String) -> String?
    func loadKeywords() -> Set<String>
}

class EmojiKeywordSuggester: KeywordSuggester {
    var keywords: Set<String> = []
    let language = "en_US"
    private let textChecker = UITextChecker()

    init() {
        self.keywords = self.loadKeywords()
    }

    func suggestion(word: String) -> String? {
        var completions = (textChecker.completionsForPartialWordRange(word.fullRange, inString: word, language: language) ?? []) as! [String]
        let guesses = (textChecker.guessesForWordRange(word.fullRange, inString: word, language: language) ?? []) as! [String]

        completions.appendContentsOf(guesses)
        completions = completions.filter(self.keywords.contains)

        guard completions.count > 0 else { return nil }
        return completions[0]
    }

    func loadKeywords() -> Set<String> {
        //TODO: load CSV from file
        return ["happy", "smile", "nature", "mushroom", "eye", "poop", "icecream", "food", "grin", "face"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, these two lines:

> ```
> guard completions.count > 0 else { return nil }
> return completions[0]
> ```

can be simplified as just this:

```
return completions.first
```

It does exactly the logic you've implemented, except that it's far more clear what the intent is.  Moreover, if ever you need to do this in the case that `completions` isn't a local variable, your approach is not thread safe.

---

Taking a look at the bigger picture, I don't understand the purpose of `loadKeywords` neither as part of the protocol nor as a method itself.

It appears that the only real reason that they exist is because they are used by the `suggestion()` method.  Since you haven't included the code that is actually using this protocol, I can only guess, but my best guess is that it's completely not needed.  Instead, I would take an approach like this with the protocol:

```
protocol KeywordSuggesterProtocol {
    func canSuggestForKeyword(keyword: String) -> Bool
    func suggestionForKeyword(keyword: String) -> String
}
```

Notice here, no optionals.

It potentially make sense for the protocol to simply be the second method and have it return an optional, simply returning `nil` where the first method would have return `false`.  But potentially, `suggestionForKeyword` might be an expensive operation (although I suppose it could be optimized).  So a protocol like this:

```
protocol KeywordSuggesterProtocol {
    func suggestionForKeyword(keyword: String) -> String?
}
```

could work as well.

The code that actually makes use of the protocol would look like one of the following two snippets (based on which protocol you're using):

```
class Foo {
    weak var suggester: KeywordSuggesterProtocol?

    // ...

    func someFuncThatNeedsKeywords(keyword: String) {
        var suggestedWord: String?
        if suggester?.canSuggestForKeyword(keyword) {
            suggestedWord = suggester?.suggestionForKeyword(keyword)
        } 
    }

    // ...
}
```

... or ...

```
class Foo {
    weak var suggester: KeywordSuggesterProtocol?

    // ...

    func someFuncThatNeedsKeywords(keyword: String) {
        let suggestedWord = suggester?.suggestionForKeyword(keyword) 
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hmm, the latter is probably better honestly.

---

As for your implementation, let's take a look at your initialization...

```
class EmojiKeywordSuggester: KeywordSuggester {
    var keywords: Set<String> = []
    let language = "en_US"
    private let textChecker = UITextChecker()

    init() {
        self.keywords = self.loadKeywords()
    }

    // stuff
}
```

First of all, `language` and `keywords` should be private.  But also, the `loadKeywords` method really isn't useful to us at all beyond initializing the `keywords`, right?  So, let's take this approach...

```
class EmojiKeywordSuggester: KeywordSuggester {
    private let keywords: Set<String> = {
        //TODO: load CSV from file
        return ["happy", "smile", "nature", "mushroom", "eye", "poop", "icecream", "food", "grin", "face"]   
    }()

    private let language = "en_US"

    private let textChecker = UITextChecker()

    // init no longer necessary
}
```

Now, it may come a time when you actually want to implement loading the keywords from CSV, in which case, we'd want something like this:

```
class EmojiKeywordSuggester: KeywordSuggester {
    private let keywords: Set<String>
    private let language = "en_US"
    private let textChecker = UITextChecker()

    init?(csvFilePath: NSURL) {
        guard let loadedKeywords = loadKeywordsFromCSV(csvFilePath) else {
            keywords = []
            return nil
        }
        keywords = loadedKeywords
    }

    private func loadKeywordsFromCSV(csvFilePath: NSURL) -> Set<String>? {
        // logic to load from the URL (which could be a local file URL)
        // this can of course fail, and return nil
    }
}
```

It's a failable initializer that fails when we can't load the keywords from the file path.

Comment: Hello im facing an issue with Value of type 'String' has no member 'fullRange'. would you please help me.

Comment: That's because this post is nearly 5 years old and the language has changed a lot in that time.